Show that vectors ${\alpha,\beta,\gamma ,\delta \in R^3}$ , ${\alpha \times \beta, \alpha \times \gamma, \alpha \times \delta}$ are linearly dependent
Show that for any given vectors ${\alpha,\beta,\gamma ,\delta \in R^3}$ , ${\alpha \times \beta, \alpha \times \gamma, \alpha \times \delta}$
the system is linearly dependent
${\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\beta} = [a_2b_3-b_2a_3,-a_1b_3+b_1a_3,a_1b_2-a_2b_1]}$
${\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\gamma} = [a_2c_3-c_2a_3,-a_1c_3+c_1a_3,a_1c_2-a_2c_1]}$
${\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\delta} = [a_2d_3-d_2a_3,-a_1d_3+d_1a_3,a_1d_2-a_2d_1]}$
then I tried to find non-zero ${a', b', c'}$ such that:
${ a'*\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\beta}+b'*\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\gamma}+c'*\vec{\alpha}\times\vec{\delta}}=0$
but all the calculations seem to be overcomplicated.
I also observed that since we have 4 vectors in $R^3$ then one of them must be a linear combinations of the others but I have no idea how to use it.

You have three vectors which are orthogonal to $a$. Namely, you have three vectors which lie in a 2 dimensional space.

Since the vectors $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,\delta \in \mathbb{R}^3$, one of them must be linearly dependent, we can assume without loss of generality that that vector is $\delta$. Therefore:
$\delta = A\alpha + B \beta + C \gamma$ where $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$
Let's define the following vectors:
$v_1 = \alpha \times\beta, v_2 = \alpha \times \gamma$ and $v_3 = \alpha \times \delta$
With this notation, your initial goal is equivalent to show that the set $\left \{ v_1, v_2,v_3 \right \}$ has only two independent vectors. We will show that $v_3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.
I'll use the descomposition we introduced at the begining.
$v_3 = \alpha \times \delta = \alpha \times (A\alpha + B \beta + C \gamma) = A\alpha \times \alpha + B\alpha\times\beta + C\alpha\times\gamma = 0 + Bv_1+ Cv_2$.
$\Rightarrow v_3 = Bv_1+ Cv_2$.
And now its clear that $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, hence the set $\left \{ v_1, v_2,v_3 \right \}$ has only two independent vectors.
